# One to one relationship Entity Framework foreign key mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-6

I am working on assigning a relationship between two objects but I am getting an error on the mapping.

I have the following objects:

```
public abstract class EntityBase : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ManagerUser : EntityBase
{
    public string UserCode { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual Staff StaffDetails { get; set; }
}

public class Staff : EntityBase
{
    public string UserCode { get; set; }
    public string DOB { get; set; }
}

public class ManagerUserMap : EntityMapBase<ManagerUser>
{
    protected override void SetupMappings()
    {
        base.SetupMappings();
        //this.HasKey(t => t.UserCode);
        this.ToTable("ManagerUsers");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("ManagerUsersID")
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.Property(t => t.Title).HasColumnName("txtTitle");
        this.HasRequired(x => x.StaffDetails)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserCode);
    }
}

public class StaffMap : EntityMapBase<Staff>
{
    protected override void SetupMappings()
    {
        base.SetupMappings();
        //this.HasKey(t => t.UserCode);
        this.ToTable("TblStaff");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("StaffID")
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.Property(t => t.UserCode).HasColumnName("User_Code");
        this.Property(t => t.DateOfBirth).HasColumnName("dob");
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> The type of property 'UserCode' on entity 'ManagerUser' does not match
>   the type of property 'Id' on entity 'Staff' in the referential
>   constraint 'ManagerUser_StaffDetails'

I have searched around and failed to find a solution to get it to compare the the foreign key in `ManagerUser` with the `UserCode` property in `Staff` instead of the `ID` property.

Comment: You are assigning UserCode as primary key for both ManagerUser and Staff and at the sametime, you are stating the UserCode is a foreignkey for the Staff...

Comment: You can't do that in EF6. EF6 can create FK only to the PK of the "principal" of the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Your keys are a bit messed up in the fluent config, HasKey sets the primary key for the entity. Below I have set the primary key to be Id for both entities. Then use the Usercode as a FK:

```
    public class ManagerUserMap : EntityMapBase<ManagerUser>
    {
        protected override void SetupMappings()
        {
            base.SetupMappings();
            this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
            this.ToTable("ManagerUsers");
            this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("ManagerUsersID")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            this.Property(t => t.Title).HasColumnName("txtTitle");
            this.HasRequired(x => x.StaffDetails)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserCode);
        }
    }

    public class StaffMap : EntityMapBase<Staff>
    {
        protected override void SetupMappings()
        {
            base.SetupMappings();
            this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
            this.ToTable("TblStaff");
            this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("StaffID")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            this.Property(t => t.UserCode).HasColumnName("User_Code");
            this.Property(t => t.DateOfBirth).HasColumnName("dob");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've edited the code in my post. UserCode is not the primary key for either table. 
In the database Staff.UserCode is linked to ManagerUser.UserCode.
I think I need to somehow tell it to link ManagerUser.UserCode to Staff.UserCode instead of ManagerUser.UserCode to Staff.ID.

Comment: Try the updated code. Make sure your DB is up to date.